# Epoch counter with TensorFlow Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm changing my TensorFlow code from the old queue interface to the new [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset). In my old code I kept track of the epoch count by incrementing a `tf.Variable` every time a new input tensor is accessed and processed in the queue. I'd like to have this epoch count with the new Dataset API, but I'm having some trouble making it work.

Since I'm producing a variable amount of data items in the pre-processing stage, it is not a simple matter of incrementing a (Python) counter in the training loop - I need to compute the epoch count with respect to the input of the queues or Dataset.

I mimicked what I had before with the old queue system, and here is what I ended up with for the Dataset API (simplified example):

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():

    data = tf.ones(shape=(10, 512), dtype=tf.float32, name="data")
    input_tensors = (data,)

    epoch_counter = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32,
                                trainable=False)

    def pre_processing_func(data_):
        data_size = tf.constant(0.1, dtype=tf.float32)
        epoch_counter_op = tf.assign_add(epoch_counter, data_size)
        with tf.control_dependencies([epoch_counter_op]):
            # normally I would do data-augmentation here
            results = (tf.expand_dims(data_, axis=0),)
            return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(results)

    dataset_source = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input_tensors)
    dataset = dataset_source.flat_map(pre_processing_func)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    # ... do something with 'dataset' and print
    # the value of 'epoch_counter' every once a while
```

However, this doesn't work. It crashes with a cryptic error message:

```
 TypeError: In op 'AssignAdd', input types ([tf.float32, tf.float32])
 are not compatible with expected types ([tf.float32_ref, tf.float32])
```

Closer inspection shows that the `epoch_counter` variable might not be accessible within the `pre_processing_func` at all. Does it live in a different graph perhaps?

Any idea how to fix the above example? Or how to get the epoch counter (with decimal points, e.g. 0.4 or 2.9) through some other means?

Comment: `assign_add` expect its first argument to be a *mutable* tensor. By making your `epoch_counter` variable non-trainable, aren't you making it *immutable*?

Comment: @valentin No, as far as I understand it is the `tf.Variable` that makes it mutable, this has nothing to do with the `trainable` argument. From the documentation it seems that `trainable=False` only makes the variable not added to the `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`. Anyway, I tested without and behaviour is the same.

Comment: I see. It was a random guess. I can't find any definition for what tensorflow considers to be a *mutable* tensor... From the error, tensorflow seems to be considering your `epoch_counter` to be immutable. Have you tried passing `epoch_counter._ref()` to `assign_add` instead of `epoch_counter` itself?

Comment: @valentin OK, thanks anyway :-) No, adding `._ref()` doesn't help either. I believe the problem is more fundamental, because 1) it worked before with the old queues, and 2) if I print `epoch_counter` in the line before `assign_add` it prints `<tf.Variable 'epoch_counter:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>`, so the type seems OK. That's why I call the error message cryptic.

Comment: I find tensorflow sometimes immature and undocumented. I believe your best option is to open an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues. I found tensorflow developers to be quite responsive. You might have stumbled upon a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Replace the definition of `epoch_counter` with the following:

```
epoch_counter = tf.get_variable("epoch_counter", initializer=0.0,
                                trainable=False, use_resource=True)
```

---

There are some limitations around using TensorFlow variables inside `tf.data.Dataset` transformations. The principle limitation is that all variables must be "resource variables" and not the older "reference variables"; unfortunately `tf.Variable` still creates "reference variables" for backwards compatibility reasons.

Generally speaking, I wouldn't recommend using variables in a `tf.data` pipeline if it's possible to avoid it. For example, you might be able to use `Dataset.range()` to define an epoch counter, and then do something like:

```
epoch_counter = tf.data.Dataset.range(NUM_EPOCHS)
dataset = epoch_counter.flat_map(lambda i: tf.data.Dataset.zip(
    (pre_processing_func(data), tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(i).repeat()))
```

The above snippet attaches an epoch counter to every value as a second component.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @mrry's great answer, if you want to stay within the `tf.data` pipeline and also want to track the iteration within each epoch you can try my solution below. If you have non-unit batch size I guess you would have to add the line `data = data.batch(bs)`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import itertools

def step_counter(): 
    for i in itertools.count(): yield i

num_examples = 3
num_epochs = 2
num_iters = num_examples * num_epochs

features = tf.data.Dataset.range(num_examples)
labels = tf.data.Dataset.range(num_examples)
data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((features, labels))
data = data.shuffle(num_examples)

step = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(step_counter, tf.int32)
data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((data, step))

epoch = tf.data.Dataset.range(num_epochs)
data = epoch.flat_map(
    lambda i: tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        (data, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(i).repeat())))

data = data.repeat(num_epochs)
it = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
example = it.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(num_iters):
        ((x, y), st), ep = sess.run(example)
        print(f'step {st} \t epoch {ep} \t x {x} \t y {y}')
```

Prints:

```
step 0   epoch 0     x 2     y 2
step 1   epoch 0     x 0     y 0
step 2   epoch 0     x 1     y 1
step 0   epoch 1     x 2     y 2
step 1   epoch 1     x 0     y 0
step 2   epoch 1     x 1     y 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `data = data.repeat(num_epochs)` results in repeating the already for num_epochs repeated dataset (also the epoch counter). Can easily be obtained by replacing `for _ in range(num_iters):` with `for _ in range(num_iters+1):`.

Answer (score 0):

I extended the example code of numerica to batches and replaced the `itertool` part:

```
num_examples = 5
num_epochs = 4
batch_size = 2
num_iters = int(num_examples * num_epochs / batch_size)

features = tf.data.Dataset.range(num_examples)
labels = tf.data.Dataset.range(num_examples)

data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((features, labels))
data = data.shuffle(num_examples)

epoch = tf.data.Dataset.range(num_epochs)
data = epoch.flat_map(
    lambda i: tf.data.Dataset.zip((
        data,
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(i).repeat(),
        tf.data.Dataset.range(num_examples)
    ))
)

# to flatten the nested datasets
data = data.map(lambda samples, *cnts: samples+cnts )
data = data.batch(batch_size=batch_size)

it = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
x, y, ep, st = it.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(num_iters):
        x_, y_, ep_, st_ = sess.run([x, y, ep, st])
        print(f'step {st_}\t epoch {ep_} \t x {x_} \t y {y_}')
```