# How can I know which TFRecords file is reading now?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a list named `t_list = [a.tfrecords, b.tfrecords, c.tfrecords, d.tfrecords]`, which contains 4 TFRecords paths named `a.tfrecords`, `b.tfrecords`, `c.tfrecords` and `d.tfrecords`.

I'm reading these TFRecords with `dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(t_list)`. And I set a `epoch_num` by `dataset = dataset.repeat(epoch_num)`

I have two questions about this function:

1. How can I know which TFRecords file is been reading now during training?
2. How can I know which epoch is now during training?

Thanks!

Comment: For your second question, have a look there:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410778/epoch-counter-with-tensorflow-dataset-api

Comment: @BiBi, Thank you for your reply! It's really helpful.