# How to set epoch counter when using TFRecordDataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm reading dataset from TFRecord files using `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`.

And I'm trying to figure out which epoch is processing at each step.

I've tried the answer from [Epoch counter with TensorFlow Dataset API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410778/epoch-counter-with-tensorflow-dataset-api), but it seems doesn't work with me.

Here's the detail: 100 samples are saved in a TFRecord file, batch_size is set to 50, epoch_num is set to 5.

Here's my simplified code:

```
def read_and_decode_TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path, batch_size, epoch_num):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path)
    dataset = dataset.map(parser_deblur)
    epoch = tf.data.Dataset.range(epoch_num)
    dataset = epoch.flat_map(lambda i: tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        (dataset, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(i).repeat())))
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epoch_num).shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    (face_blur_batch, face_gt_batch), epochNow = iterator.get_next()
    return face_blur_batch, face_gt_batch, epochNow
print EPOCH: {epochNow}, STEP: {step}
```

What I expect is :

```
EPOCH: [0 0 0 ... 0 0] (fifty zero), STEP: 1
EPOCH: [0 0 0 ... 0 0] (fifty zero), STEP: 2 
EPOCH: [1 1 1 ... 1 1] (fifty one), STEP: 3
EPOCH: [1 1 1 ... 1 1] (fifty one), STEP: 4
EPOCH: [2 2 2 ... 2 2] (fifty two), STEP: 5
EPOCH: [2 2 2 ... 2 2] (fifty two), STEP: 6
EPOCH: [3 3 3 ... 3 3] (fifty three), STEP: 7
EPOCH: [3 3 3 ... 3 3] (fifty three), STEP: 8
EPOCH: [4 4 4 ... 4 4] (fifty four), STEP: 9
EPOCH: [4 4 4 ... 4 4] (fifty four), STEP: 10
```

But the actual output is :

```
EPOCH: [2 0 4 ... 4 1] , STEP: 1
EPOCH: [4 0 2 ... 3 4] , STEP: 2 
EPOCH: [4 0 3 ... 2 2] , STEP: 3
EPOCH: [1 1 3 ... 1 3] , STEP: 4
EPOCH: [1 4 0 ... 0 1] , STEP: 5
EPOCH: [0 4 4 ... 4 3] , STEP: 6
EPOCH: [3 1 0 ... 3 2] , STEP: 7
EPOCH: [4 2 4 ... 3 1] , STEP: 8
EPOCH: [0 0 1 ... 3 3] , STEP: 9
EPOCH: [3 1 3 ... 3 2] , STEP: 10
```

I have no idea what the output EPOCH is? It seems random. And it's different every running.

Any idea how to fix the above code? Or how to get the epoch counter through some other means?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question. The problem is, I shuffled after assigning `EPOCH`. The right order should be shuffle first:

```
def read_and_decode_TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path, batch_size, epoch_num):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path)
    dataset = dataset.map(parser_deblur).shuffle(buffer_size=100*batch_size)
    epoch = tf.data.Dataset.range(epoch_num)
    dataset = epoch.flat_map(lambda i: tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        (dataset, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(i).repeat())))
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epoch_num).batch(batch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    (face_blur_batch, face_gt_batch), epochNow = iterator.get_next()
    return face_blur_batch, face_gt_batch, epochNow
print EPOCH: {epochNow}, STEP: {step}
```