# Control epoch with custom Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

My input function looks like this:

```
    def input_fn():
        dataset.repeat(epochs).batch(16)
    estimator_model.train(input_fn, steps)
```

How can I notify my model that this is n-th repetition (epoch) over dataset? I would like to implement things like decaying learning rate, training model without adversarial loss for first n epochs etc. I am using tf.data.Dataset and tf.estimator.Estimator.
If I call train method multiple times:

```
    def input_fn():
        dataset.batch(16)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        estimator_model.train(input_fn, steps)
```

it will rebuild model (different weights, different checkpoint dir, different tensorflow logs) - that's unacceptable for me.

Before estimator I would do:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for iter, data in enumerate(dataset):
        model.train(data, epoch)
```

Now such code is deep within guts of Estimator and Dataset, and I have no control over it - so it is hard for me to do things like decaying learning rate, etc. (do something for first/last `n` epochs).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of your train set you can set a parameter `steps_per_epoch = train_size//batch_size`. Then in your `model_fn` query the `global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()` tensor and then get the number of epochs that have passed as a tensor `epochs_passed = tf.cast(global_step, tf.float32)/steps_per_epoch`.

For many applications like the learning rate schedule you mentioned it's often more idiomatic to just use [`tf.train.piecewise_constant_decay`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/piecewise_constant_decay) which is based around a similar concept.

Comment: Calculating steps_per_epoch is not a way I would like to follow, because I need to write separate code for handling all augments etc.

Comment: `piecewise_constant_decay` seems reasonable, but suffers from same problems, additionally many papers define parameters in terms of epochs.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to write separate code for handling all augments"? You can calculate `steps_per_epoch` as a python `float` and just pass it in through `params` in the `Estimator` call. Any tensor written here is globally available in your `model_fn`. What extra functionality do you need?

Comment: If i augment my dataset with horizontal flip suddenly my dataset grows twice, so I need to write code that checks if augment is applied and calculates dataset size. And so on. That is unnecessary boilerplate I would like to avoid.

Comment: If you're willing to add the epoch counter to either `features` or `labels` you can do it from the `input_fn` but the code is pretty gnarly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47417440/11434940